# C - Comparing an element in an array with all the previous ones

Tags: c, arrays

I have a loop that generates random numbers. I want to compare the random number generated in the current iteration with random numbers generated in all the previous iterations and `break` when there is match between two random numbers.
This is what I have so far, but it only compares the current random number with the one that is generated right before it.

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    a[i] = (100*(1 + rand() % 12)) + (1 + rand() % 30);

    for (j = i - 1; j < SIZE; ++j)
    {
        if (a[i] != a[j])
        {
            printf("Person %i - %i\n", i, a[i]);
        }
        else break; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered keeping the array sorted while generating those numbers?

Comment: It looks like the numbers generated are in a small range. Have you considered using a HashMap or may be a bit array to keep track of what random numbers have been generated so far?

Comment: @hbagdi how would that help? I'm just a beginner and I feel like that would unnecessarily complicate things.

Comment: Whyever do you expect this dodgy loop `for (j = i - 1; j < SIZE; ++j)` to work, when you have not even entered values at those `[j]` array elements yet?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that (Hashmap & bit array)

Comment: Has nothing to do with hashmaps or bit arrays. You are looking at values you have not even yet entered.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hmm I don't know. I know it doesn't work, but I want a[j] or something to represent all the a[i] that come before a[i].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    a[i] = (100*(1 + rand() % 12)) + (1 + rand() % 30);
    found = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        if (a[i] == a[j])
        {
             found = 1;
             break;
        }
    }
    if(!found) 
    {
        printf("Person %i - %i\n", i, a[i]);
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @SpiderPig! Hmm I tried that but it doesn't work.  Right now SIZE = 100 and it keeps going all the way up to 99, and I don't know why it prints out every iteration about 10 times—a problem that I have been having repeatedly.

Comment: Wait, I think it works! I didn't realize you had edited your answer. Grazie mille @SpiderPig